# To prove the following statement by induction for positive nature number n.

Tags: induction

There are both $n$ and $k$ in this formula and I don’t know how to prove it. Because in this case I cannot split the summation into parts contains the assumption.

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(2k-1)2k} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}$$

My basic case is $n=1$ and both LHS and RHS equals to $\frac{1}{2}$.
Assume the statement is true for some m
$$ie.  \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{(2k-1)2k} = \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{m+k}$$
I want to prove for $m+1$
$$ie.  \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \frac{1}{(2k-1)2k} = \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \frac{1}{m+1+k}$$
RHS I got
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \frac{1}{m+1+k}=\sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{m+1+k}+\frac{1}{m+1+m+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{m+1+k}+\frac{1}{2m+2}$$
LHS i got
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} \frac{1}{(2k-1)2k} = \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{(2k-1)2k} + \frac{1}{(2(m+1)-1)2(m+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{m+k}+\frac{1}{(2m+2)(2m+1)}$$
And I got stuck here.Because RHS it is $m+1+k$ on the denominator but on LHS it is $m+k$ and they are quite different I don't know how to prove them equal.

Comment: Did you at least try to prove it for the base case? Did you establish a hypothesis?

Comment: Yes. I edited the question. Sorry I just used this site for the first time and I just learnt how to type equations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can split it.

HINT: $$\frac1{2k(2k-1)}=\frac1{2k-1}-\frac1{2k}\,,$$

so

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{2k(2k-1)}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k(2k-1)}=\frac1{2n+1}-\frac1{2(n+1)}\,.$$

**Edit:** And

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{n+1+k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+k}&=\sum_{k=2}^{n+2}\frac1{n+k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+k}\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2}-\frac1{n+1}\,.
\end{align*}$$

The only terms in the first summation that do not appear in the second are the last two, with $k=n+1$ and $k=n+2$, and the only term in the second summation that does not appear in the first is the $k=1$ term: everything else cancels out. Thus, you’ll have the induction step once you show that

$$\frac1{2n+1}-\frac1{2(n+1)}=\frac1{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2}-\frac1{n+1}\,,$$

which is just a matter of a little algebra.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{-1}{(n+1+k)(n+k)}+\frac{1}{2n+2}$$ this is what I got when I tried to figure out the second equation. Still I found noway out. Sorry I am not so clever. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @lllll: I’d prefer not to tell you directly right away. First I’d like you to try writing out the case $n=2$, expanding the summations in full; that should make it a little easier to see what’s going on. For the difference that I asked you to figure out you should get three terms, two positive and one negative.

Comment: Yes I wrote out the case $n=2$ they both equal to $\frac{7}{12}$. And the difference is it $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(n+k+1} + \frac{1}{2(n+1)} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k}$? I need to prove the two differences equal, right? But how should I get rid of the summation in the second difference?

Comment: @lllll: I see now: you’re going about it wrong. I showed you how much the lefthand sum increases when you go from $n$ to $n+1$; my question was designed to get you to calculate how much the righthand sum increases when you go from $n$ to $n+1$. If you do that correctly, a very little algebra is needed to show that the increases are the same. That gives you your induction step: if the sums are equal for $n$, and they increase by the same amount when you change $n$ to $n+1$, then they’re equal for $n+1$ as well. Does that help?

Comment: I can understand the increase by the same part. But I really don't know how to calculate out the correct difference.;(((

Comment: @lllll: Okay; give me a few minutes, and I’ll add that calculation.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much.

Comment: @lllll: Done: I’ve left just a little bit for you at the end.

Comment: Yes!! I see how to do it now! Thank you!!

Comment: @lllll: You’re welcome!